# Replacing spaces without concatenating lines in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to replace all spaces in Notepad using regular expressions. I am finding "/s" and replacing with "_". Only issue is all the lines get concatenated into 1 big line. Any suggestions on how to limit the replacement process so that it only includes spaces in between words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\h` instead of `\s`, it stands for any **h**orizontal space.

Comment: Thanks, such an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

don't use `\s` as it means one whitespace character. meaning, it can be a space, a tab or even a new line. if you just want to replace spaces, use `<space>`(" ") instead.